# Add double hline in table below caption

Tags: tables, captions, rules

I would like to insert a double `\hline` below the caption in my table.  The caption is positioned at the top of my table.  MWE is below.  The `%\hline \hline` line is where I would like the double `\hline` to be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Title}
%\hline \hline 
\begin{tabular}{lc}
Column heading & More column heading
\hline
Data & More data
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to define a `ruled` style (adjust the settings to suit):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{ruled}{
  #1#2#3\par\vspace{-.65\baselineskip}\hrulefill\par\vspace{-.83\baselineskip}\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[table]{format=ruled}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Title}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
Stuff & More stuff 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if your table begins with a horizontal rule, this might look odd.

If the double rules should be part of the tabular material, you can use for example `booktabs` and its rule commands to define the double rule (in an example below I used `\specialrule` to illustrate some control on the spacing requested in comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\doubleRule{\toprule\toprule}
\newcommand\doublerule{\toprule\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\doublerulesep}{0.95em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A test table}
\begin{tabular}{l r}
\doubleRule
Header1 & Header2 \\
\midrule
Column1a & Column 2a \\
Column1a & Column 2a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\captionsetup{skip=2pt}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A test table}
\begin{tabular}{l r}
\doublerule
Header1 & Header2 \\
\midrule
Column1a & Column 2a \\
Column1a & Column 2a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I extended my MWE to be a more complete example of the kind of tables I would like to make.  Does your suggestion work in this case?

Comment: @Joshua Of course. I have a doubt now, however: are the two rules supossed to be part of the tabular material or are they supossed to be part of the caption?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me, as long as they span the entire width of the table.  I would prefer them to be closer to the caption than the tabular (like you have above).

Comment: @Joshua Please see my updated answer. Is is something like that what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

After examining Gonzalo Medina's excellent answer, I realized there was a simple mistake I was making that prevented the double `\hline` from working.  I needed to move it into the `tabular` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Title}
\begin{tabular}{lc}  %These two lines are switched
\hline \hline        %These two lines are switched
Column heading & More column heading
\hline
Data & More data
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The above code works just fine, and it only requires swapping two lines from the code of my original question.